# Connecting to Google Cloud SQL from a Google Cloud Function python3.7

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql, pymysql

I'm trying to connect using pymysql, using code very close to the example provided in the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/sql#functions_sql_mysql-python

The database have public ip, with no authorized networks (since cf should use a socket), and my user created allowing access from anywhere.

Running locally with the Cloud SQL Proxy works just fine, but on Google Cloud I get connection refused.

**Edit: updated example with code to run locally with env vars**

```
import logging
import os

import pymysql
from pymysql.err import OperationalError


mysql_conn = None


def __get_cursor():
    try:
        return mysql_conn.cursor()
    except OperationalError:
        mysql_conn.ping(reconnect=True)
        return mysql_conn.cursor()


def get_config():
    return {
        'unix_socket': f'/cloudsql/{os.environ["CONNECTION_NAME"]}',
        'user': os.environ['DB_USER'],
        'password': os.environ['DB_PASSWORD'],
        'db': os.environ['DB_NAME'],
        'charset': 'utf8mb4',
        'cursorclass': pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
        'autocommit': True
    }


def mysql_demo(request):
    global mysql_conn

    if not mysql_conn:
        mysql_config = get_config()
        logging.info('Open db with config: %s', mysql_config)

        try:
            mysql_conn = pymysql.connect(**mysql_config)
        except OperationalError as exception:
            logging.warning('Unable to get db connection: %s', str(exception))
            return

    with __get_cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('SELECT NOW() as now')
        results = cursor.fetchone()
        return str(results['now'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    os.environ['CONNECTION_NAME'] = 'my-project:us-central1:cf-test'
    os.environ['DB_USER'] = 'db-user'
    os.environ['DB_PASSWORD'] = 'db-password'
    os.environ['DB_NAME'] = 'db_name'
    logging.info(mysql_demo(None))
```

**Edit: additional output**

When running locally, this prints out:

```
INFO:root:2019-09-24 07:11:54
```

When running as a cloud function I get the output: `

```
2019-09-24 09:14:59.279 CEST test-cloud-sql mesuju89uxuw Open db with config: {'unix_socket': '/cloudsql/boeingfda-jal:us-central1:cf-test', 'user': 'enplore', 'password': 'az2labha', 'db': 'content_enplore_auth', 'charset': 'utf8mb4', 'cursorclass': <class 'pymysql.cursors.DictCursor'>, 'autocommit': True}
2019-09-24 09:14:59.856 CEST test-cloud-sql mesuju89uxuw Unable to get db connection: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
```

Comment: Just as a debug... 

1) Confirm that you're using a 2nd generation MySQL instance on Cloud SQL, right?
2) print out: {CONNECTION_NAME}. Just to be sure it's being set on the environment of the GCF properly. If you run the function in the console as a test, you should see any output to STDOUT.

Comment: 1. Database instance verified to be a second generation
2. Full mysql config printed and verified to use correct unix_socket (/cloudsql/*redacted*:us-central1:cf-test), user, password and db.
3. Running the function locally, with a cloud SQL proxy up gives me the expected output of todays date and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is often more helpful if you post the error you've received, as it often provides extra context. Here are a few probable causes:

- Make sure the Cloud SQL Admin API is enabled.
- Verify the service account (defaults to `service-[YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER]@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com`) you are using to run the instance has the correct IAM permissions ( `Cloud SQL Client` role or the `cloudsql.instances.connect` and `cloudsql.instances.get` permissions).
- Finally, verify that `CONNECTION_NAME` variable isn't misspelled.

Finally, you should consider using a connection pool (like SQLAlchemy) and set the max limit to 1. The connection pool will handle errors more gracefully, and limit the number of connects used per instance.

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed what got me, I had missed to add the cloud sql client permissions to the service account for the cloud function.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your unix_socket entry is not generated properly. It accepts the data in the following format:

```
'/cloudsql/project-id:region:instance-name'
```

Example:

```
'/cloudsql/my-awesome-project:us-central1:mysqlinst1'
```

To get the exact connection name you can use the following command:

```
gcloud sql instances describe <instance_name> | grep connectionName
```